# Videogular - path to mp4 file not working on Android (but on iOS yes)

Tags: android, html, cordova, ionic-framework, videogular

i have following config for video files for playing:

```
$scope.availableTimelapseVideos = [
          {
            name: "Clouds",
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("videos/clouds.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Traffic Downtown",
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("videos/traffic_downtown.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ]
          },
          {
            name: "Vibrant Landscape",
            sources: [
              {src: $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("videos/vibrant_landscape.mp4"), type: "video/mp4"}
            ]
          }
```

It worked (but with some bugs) on Android with installed Crosswalk plugin:

http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/

But i have some reasons why i don't want to include crosswalk in my app.

So I tried to play video without the crosswalk extension.

But video is succesfully played only on iOS device.

On Android device (4.4) is not working.

I tried also different path to file like:

```
android_asset/www/videos/clouds.mp4
```

But without luck.

What is the right path to file please?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Just add '/' before your'android_asset/www/videos/clouds.mp4'.
It should be

> '/android_asset/www/videos/clouds.mp4'